# python : how to split the non-numeric character in lists?

Tags: python

I am trying to work out a simple function to split lists.

Here is one example list that i am working on

```
list

'Internet Specific                          163  23.42   163  23.45   5401.44  30.78 \n'
```

After I applied strip() and split function, i got this result.

```
list.strip().split()
['Internet', 'Specific', '163', '23.42', '163', '23.45', '5401.44', '30.78']
```

But, I want to split the list like this.

```
['Internet Specific', '163', '23.42', '163', '23.45', '5401.44', '30.78']
```

I want to split the numeric value but not the alphabet. Is there any way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like `re.split('([^0-9.]+)', v)` (where "v" is the list content) should do. Fine tuning may be necessary.

Comment: If you have fixed columns, then don't use `split`.  Store the start/end column number for each field, and use `line[start:end].strip()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use python `re` module and `re.split()` to split string.

Pattern used: `\s+(?=\d)` [This search for one or more whitespace before digit]

Code:

```
import re
data = 'Internet Specific                          163  23.42   163  23.45   5401.44  30.78'
result = re.split("\s+(?=\d)", data)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['Internet Specific', '163', '23.42', '163', '23.45', '5401.44', '30.78']
```

Answer (score 0):

@gajendragarg's answer works only when all but the first column is numeric, and also leaves the last item with unwanted whitespace characters unless the string is preprocessed by stripping whitespaces (note that there is a white space and a newline character at the end of the input string in the OP's question, while there is none in @gajendragarg's answer).

Instead of splitting, it would be more fool-proof and generic in this case to use `re.findall` to capture what you need--a sequence of either a non-whitespace character or a whitespace character that's preceded by and followed by a non-whitespace character:

```
import re

s = 'Internet Specific                          163  23.42   163  23.45   5401.44  30.78 \n'
print(re.findall(r'(?:\S|(?<=\S)\s(?=\S))+', s))
```

This outputs:

```
['Internet Specific', '163', '23.42', '163', '23.45', '5401.44', '30.78']
```

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my answer. Your pattern works well for this input string but it took `357` steps to find matches where searching for whitespace with my pattern took `85` steps only. And unwanted whitespace character can be striped with `str.strip()` as it as fast for removing whitespace. I like your generic pattern! Is it possible that your pattern can be more optimised? 